# change top margin of second page using mPDF

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm dynamically generating PDFs with an unknown page count. mPDF is working good, but the top margin on the second page is gone. How can I set the margins for all pages with the document?

I've tried the following, but it has no effect:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('', '', 0, '', 15, 15, 15, 15, 8, 8);
```

Comment: how you are creating page ....have you tried AddPage...command

Comment: @aligarian I can't use add page because the length of the page is unknown. I can't break it an any specific point. The second page is the continuation from the first

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was able to find an answer. Here it is in case anyone needs it:

define the margins using `@page` like:

```
@page *{
    margin-top: 2.54cm;
    margin-bottom: 2.54cm;
    margin-left: 3.175cm;
    margin-right: 3.175cm;
}
</style>';
```

Reference: http://www.mpdf1.com/forum/discussion/80

Comment: it also needs to be pointed out that @page selector should be the first selector in the CSS otherwise it can be ignored by mPDF.

Comment: This did not do anything for me. Removed the asterisk, and it worked. `@page` styles make it impossible to have a header or footer in my experience so far.

Comment: Hi all, I added more stackoverflow related reference for those who need to do this kind of CSS thing.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492432/any-way-to-css-select-all-except-the-first-page

2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50833991/css-page-settings-for-second-page

I have tested those reference, and it works.

Answer (score 23):

You can use something like this. it seems to work.

define the margins using @page like:

```
<?php
    include("mpdf.php");
    $html='<style>@page {
     margin: 0px;
    }</style>


    ';
    $mpdf=new mPDF('','A4');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output();
    ?>
```

Comment: `@page` styles makes it impossible to have a header or footer in my experience.

Answer (score 6):

```
$mpdf->AddPage('L','','','','',50,50,50,50,10,10);
```

Reference: [Mpdf documentation](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/addpage.html)

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same problem, it helped me to set the margin_footer->0

```
$mpdf=new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['margin_footer' => 0]);
```