# CSS @page settings for second page

Tags: css, printing, weasyprint

I have placed in my CSS code setting for @page:first and @page as they require different footer details.

However what I need to do is alter settings for page 2 specifically as this page by design will be blank.

I need to update the second page to have no footer details. Is this something that can be done?

```
 @page:first{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    content:counter(page);
    @bottom-right {
        content: element(footer2);
        }
}

@page{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    @bottom-right {
        content: element(footer);
        }
}
```

Comment: The `@page` CSS at-rule is used to modify some CSS properties when printing a document. You can't change all CSS properties with `@page`. You can only change the margins, orphans, widows, and page breaks of the document. Attempts to change any other CSS properties will be ignored.

Comment: I already know this. My question is not about the capabilities of what '@page' can do in terms of properties. My question is about whether or not i can change things like margins on the 2nd print page specifically using '@page'.

Comment: Im not sure if it works with `@page` (I think so) but you can try `:nth-child(2)`

Comment: That was a good suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: did you find your answer to this? I am trying to modify the margins on my second page

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Use `@page:first` for the first page and keep using `@page` for the second page and beyond.

I could not find a solution for the 2nd page and on, `:nth-child(2)` or `@page + @page` did not work for me, but `@page:first` does work, so I ended up solving my problem with it. Hopefully it fits your needs as well.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend "named pages" and refer to the documentation.

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-page-3/#using-named-pages

Assuming your 2nd page is a section with class .title, you can figure out the rest...

```
@page title { background-color: red; }
section.title { page: title }
```

This works in WeasyPrint.